# B-Tree - Why can't there be a node with an even number of keys?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

I'm trying to implement a B-Tree according to the chapter "B-Trees" in "Introduction to Algorithms".

What I don't quite get is the "minimal degree". In the book it is stated that the **degree** is a *number which expresses the lower/upper bound for the number of keys a node can hold*. It it further says that:

1. *Every non-root node stores at least `t - 1` keys and has `t` children*.
2. *Every node stores at most `2*t - 1` keys and has `2*t` children*.

So you get for t = 2:

1. `t - 1` = 1 keys and t = 2 children
2. `2*t - 1` = 3 keys and 4 children

For t = 3

1. `t - 1` = 2 keys and t = 3 children
2. `2*t - 1` = 5 keys and 6 children

Now here's the problem: It seems that the nodes in a B-Tree can only store an *odd* number of keys when they are full.

Why can't there be a node with, let's say at most 4 keys and 5 children? Does it have something to do with splitting the node?

Comment: `in "Introduction to Algorithms"` - lo and behold! _Which_ "Introduction to Algorithms": Authors? Publishers? Language? ISBN? Hyperlink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that the nodes in a B-Tree can only store an odd number of keys?

Definitely not. The numbers you have written is minimum and maximum number ofof keys respectively, so for `t = 2`, nodes with 1, 2, 3 keys are allowed. For `t = 3`, nodes with 2, 3, 4, 5 keys are allowed.

Moreover, the root of the tree is allowed to have only 1 key.

It is possible to define (and implement) trees that have eg. 1 or 2 keys in a node (so-called 2-3 trees). The reason B-trees are defined to accommodate one more, is that this leads to faster performance. Particularly, this allows amortized `O(1)` (counting splitting and joining operations) delete and insert operations.

Comment: Of course you're right... what I meant was the case when the node is full - it then can only contain odd numbers of nodes. Still I don't get why this leads to better performance, see ire_and-curses comment.

Comment: @Helper Method: Ok, so I think the second paragraph answers your question - do you need a formal proof?

Comment: @jpalecek I have edited the original question, but the OP asked actually about when a node is full: why a full node can't not have an even number of keys? That was the actual not so clear question of the OP, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

it's not impossible but suboptimal. how do you split a node with an odd number of children?

Comment: I don't understand this argument. You take the median child, move it into the parent, and then assign all children rightwards of the median to a new sub-node of the parent.